# How Make Sure the Output file has been successfully written in VbScript?

Tags: vbscript

Here's the scenerio, I have some text files in a "FilestoMerge" Directory. I'm using VbScript to loop through each files in the directory and merge contents into one single 'output.txt' file in "Output" directory. After, the merge is successfull, I want to delete the original files. How do I make sure if the content from parent files have been successfully writen to output file before I delete it. Below is my Vbscript to merge files.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


set OutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strOutputFileName)
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")

Set FileList = WMIService.ExecQuery _
("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='C:\Users\xxxx\yyyy\FilesToMerge'} Where " _
    & "ResultClass = CIM_DataFile")

For Each file In FileList
    Set objTextFile = fso.OpenTextFile(file.Name, ForReading) 
    strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
    objTextFile.Close
    OutputFile.WriteLine strText  <<<<need to make sure this is successfull, then only delete
    fso.DeleteFile(file.Name) 
Next

OutputFile.Close
```

Comment: Has there been an occasion where it was not successful? I would think the only reason it failed is if the command had an error if the file was open. I don't think `.WriteLine` returns anything so there is nothing to gain there. If the line succeeds i see no reason to think it failed.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for reply. I think you are right, there can't be scenario where writing fails, unless as you said, the file is being used by another process. Now I have a question - If the file my script is about to read is actually being written by another process and hasn't completed because it's a huge file of about 50 Mb, what happens then?

Comment: If the file is already open in another process then attempting to open it would cause an exception that might need to be handled if that is a realistic possibility. The answer you have would help if you use the `On Error` section the address the user of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some error checking:

```
On Error Resume Next
For Each file In FileList
    Set objTextFile = fso.OpenTextFile(file.Name, ForReading) 
    strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
    objTextFile.Close
    If Err Then
        ' There's been an error reading the file
        ' Handle in some way
        Err.Clear ' Clear error
    End If
    OutputFile.WriteLine strText  <<<<need to make sure this is successfull, then only delete
    If Err Then
        ' There's been an error writing the read content to the output file
        ' Handle in some way
        Err.Clear
    End If
    fso.DeleteFile(file.Name) 
Next
On Error GoTo 0
```

You can also combine the first three lines for the reading operation into a single line:

```
strText = fso.OpenTextFile(file.Name, ForReading).ReadAll
```

No need to open, read, and close, if all you want to do is read the contents of the file in a single go.

::edit::

On second thought the above structure would be dangerous as you might handle a read error and then go on to write the content of the variable (which would be empty due to the read error) successfully to the output file and then delete the original file, as there would be no error writing to file. So use the following structure:

```
On Error Resume Next
For Each file In FileList
    strText = fso.OpenTextFile(file.Name, ForReading).ReadAll
    If Err Then
        ' There's been an error reading the file
        ' Handle in some way
        Err.Clear ' Clear error
    Else
        OutputFile.WriteLine strText
        If Err Then
            ' There's been an error writing the read content to the output file
            ' Handle in some way
            Err.Clear
        Else
            fso.DeleteFile(file.Name) 
        End If
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
```

This will only attempt to write the file if there hasn't been an error reading it, and will only attempt to delete the file if there hasn't been an error writing to OutputFile

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So, this means, if error occurs, it goes to error handling code and goes to next loop without executing the code after the error? for example, fso.delete() won't execute if error occurs during previous lines of code?  Also, Can I write like - If Err Then *handle error* Else fso.Delete?

Comment: Error handing in vbscript is very basic. `On Error Resume Next` simply tells it to continue with the next line/statement when an error occurs rather than exiting immediately with a runtime error. You then have to check for an error at appropriate points in the code - I've put the error checking after reading and writing. If you do anything other than quit after an error, then you'll want to clear the error with `Err.Clear()` after acknowledging it, otherwise the error code will remain and your next error check will pick it up again. ...[_continued_]...

Comment: In my example, `fso.Delete()` would execute because the error is handled in the `If Err` statement, and execution continues afterwards with the next statement which is `fso.DeleteFile()`. Finally yes, you can do `If Err Then _handle error_ Else fso.Delete`, which would be a good idea if you don't want to delete the file if an error occurs. For example you could do something like `If Err Then` `WScript.Echo "Error writing to file: " & Err.Description` `Err.Clear` `Else` `fso.DeleteFile(File.Path)` `End If`